# Show data from JTable in Jtextfield with 2 JFrames

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am making a program for school.

My program has two JFrame's
The first Jframe = Basisscherm
The second Jframe = Toetsenbord

On the Jframe basisscherm i've got a Jtable filled with data from MYSQL Database. This Table showing labels and with this labels are specific text so each label has his own text this is in the same data base

Now on the Jframe toetsenbord i've got a Jtextfield with the name: Tekst

Now my problem is i want to show the text in the jtextfield by selecting the label from the jtable and clicking on a ok button but i don't now where to start

Comment: 1) Don't forget to add the [tag:homework] tag to homework questions.  2) Did you have a question? 3) Please use common Java nomenclature. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your current code.

Comment: I dont have any code yet, i want to know how to start with it which method i need to use example

Comment: Check Oracle tutorial they are very nice  to learn! -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection. If you never try by yourself you will never be able to do something alone... Your question is quite basic some self-investment will resolve your problem!

Comment: Whatever happened to *"My program has an two JFrame's.."*?  Note that SO is not a code factory, so if you do not ask a more specific question, and post code, the question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. using which you can get the selected text in JTable.

```
JTable table = new JTable();

if (table.getColumnSelectionAllowed()
        && !table.getRowSelectionAllowed()) {
    // Column selection is enabled
    // Get the indices of the selected columns
    int[] vColIndices = table.getSelectedColumns();
} else if (!table.getColumnSelectionAllowed()
        && table.getRowSelectionAllowed()) {
    // Row selection is enabled
    // Get the indices of the selected rows
    int[] rowIndices = table.getSelectedRows();
} else if (table.getCellSelectionEnabled()) {
    // Individual cell selection is enabled

    // In SINGLE_SELECTION mode, the selected cell can be retrieved using
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
    int colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();

    // In the other modes, the set of selected cells can be retrieved using
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    // Get the min and max ranges of selected cells
    int rowIndexStart = table.getSelectedRow();
    int rowIndexEnd = table.getSelectionModel().getMaxSelectionIndex();
    int colIndexStart = table.getSelectedColumn();
    int colIndexEnd = table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel()
        .getMaxSelectionIndex();

    // Check each cell in the range
    for (int r=rowIndexStart; r<=rowIndexEnd; r++) {
        for (int c=colIndexStart; c<=colIndexEnd; c++) {
            if (table.isCellSelected(r, c)) {
                // cell is selected
            }
        }
    }
}
```