# Display values of a selected row from a dynamically varying JTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jscrollpane

I have to develop a front end in Swing.I have a JFrame in Netbeans with 3 panes in it.

- JScrollPane 1:it contains a JTable
- JScrollPane 2: It should display the value of the fields of the selected row
- ListPane : which contains the list of tables from which a user chooses a table to be displayed.

Now since the content of JTable varies(the no of rows and columns also vary) dynamically based on the table chosen by user I can't drag and drop the TextBoxes in the 3rd scroll pane to display the selected row's values.It would be helpful if anybody can suggest a way to do it or any pointers to problems that deal with similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to your `JList`. When a particular table is selected from the list, use `setModel()` to change the `TableModel` of your `JTable` to one that is correct for the chosen table. A related example using `setModel()` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513).

Comment: is it possible to do it in a simpler way??i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080687/show-data-from-jtable-in-jtextfield-with-2-jframes) to be useful.
so that i have to create as many textboxes as the columncount that is selected and display the respective values.

Comment: Not that I know. A `ListSelectionListener` works on a JTable, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513).